# You couldn’t find two people who are less like us

Tags: vocabulary

> “It’s — it’s true?” faltered Professor McGonagall. “After all he’s
>   done… all the people he’s killed… he couldn’t kill a little boy? It’s
>   just astounding… of all the things to stop him… but how in the name of
>   heaven did Harry survive?”
>    “We can only guess.” said
>   Dumbledore. “We may never know.”
>    Professor McGonagall pulled
>   out a lace handkerchief and dabbed at her eyes beneath her spectacles.
>   Dumbledore gave a great sniff as he took a golden watch from his
>   pocket and examined it. It was a very odd watch. It had twelve hands
>   but no numbers; instead, little planets were moving around the edge.
>   It must have made sense to Dumbledore, though, because he put it back
>   in his pocket and said, “Hagrid’s late. I suppose it was he who told
>   you I’d be here, by the way?”
>    “Yes,” said Professor McGonagall.
>   “And I don’t suppose you’re going to tell me why you’re here, of all
>   places?”
>    “I’ve come to bring Harry to his aunt and uncle.
>   They’re the only family he has left now.”
>    “You don’t mean – you
>   can’t mean the people who live here?” cried Professor McGonagall,
>   jumping to her feet and pointing at number four. “Dumbledore — you
>   can’t. I’ve been watching them all day. **You couldn’t find two people
>   who are less like us**. And they’ve got this son — I saw him kicking
>   his mother all the way up the street, screaming for sweets. Harry
>   Potter come and live here!”
>  (Harry Potter and the Sorcerer's
>   Stone)

What does the highlighted part mean?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The implication is that McGonagall is concerned about Harry's living arrangements; she thinks it would be best for Harry if he were to live with a Wizarding family who could help him grow and nurture him in their ways and with their culture and customs. The family she imagines him with is clearly not the Dursleys.

So for the actual parsing of the sentence itself: she is saying "If you searched the entire world trying to find people who are dissimilar to us (*us* being *Wizarding folk*) you would not find anyone so dissimilar as the Dursleys."

She clearly thinks this is a bad thing, and implies that she would prefer he live with a Wizarding family.

Answer (score -2):

It means the Dursleys hate wizards,
especially the Potters.

Comment: No. it doesn't. (Although the *fact* is correct, that's not what the sentence says.

Comment: Welcome to ELL.SE! You might want to take a look at [this page](http://ell.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) to see what answers are acceptable in our community. Please provide your answer with your knowledge, reliable sources and reasonable efforts.

Comment: I might agree that this is the overall implication of the entire paragraph, but I agree with @Stephie – this is **not** the meaning of the bolded sentence.